# C# DateTime to Javascript Date

Tags: javascript, c#

I am getting some DateTime values from server which I need to convert to Javascript Date.

They look like this: "2019-06-12T22:14:28.006511"

Comment: how did you get DateTime value from server ?

Comment: By an Ajax request.

Comment: Use moment.js ( https://momentjs.com/ ) or refer this answer ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/42863295/1427849 )

Comment: What timezone is that? Do you want to generate a date object based on the user timezone? Do you need to maintain the microseconds?

Comment: GMT + 03. I do not need the microseconds, and I would like to use the original time zone.

Comment: @ zey thank you very much! I can't believe it is so simple. :)

Comment: Btw it is JS not C# date format, sometimes end with Z and optional TZ.

Comment: What is your question?