# How to format an existing date from an Object in JS

Tags: javascript, time, format

I am pulling the creation date out of an object, and receiving it like this:
`2021-04-24T05:48:50.650397026Z`

How can I turn it into this?: `24.04.2021, 05:48:50`

The current date is stored in `firstDate`. Only vanilla JS please, any help is appreciated <3

```
async function getDate(image, tag) {
    return fetch('/registry/v2/' + image + '/manifests/' + tag)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => JSON.parse(data.history[0].v1Compatibility).created)

const firstDate = await getDate(imageName, tags[0]);
console.log(firstDate); // output is 2021-04-24T05:48:50.650397026Z
```

Comment: you can do something like this: `let date = new Date("2021-04-24T05:48:50.650397026Z")`
then you can get the day with `date.getDay()` or `date.getMonth()`. Combine it with a "." and you have the date in the format you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a simple utility function like below which will return you formatted date.

```js
function getFormattedDate(date) {
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var day = date.getDate();
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var time =  date.getHours() + ":" + date.getMinutes() + ":" + date.getSeconds();
    return day + "." + month + "." + year + ", " + time ;
}

console.log(getFormattedDate(new Date()))
```

Comment: The problem is that I have the dates already, the function you have gives me the current date, no? I tried implementing it in my code, but recieve the error "date.getMonth is not a function"

Comment: you can pass your string format date in `new Date(yourStringDate)` to above function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.toLocaleString` method.

```
firstDate.toLocaleString();
```

Here's a more thorough answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/42863295/1825010

Answer (score -2):

Recommend to use [Dayjs](https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format) if possible, since you can customize the format as you need. It's a very light-weight date formating package (only 2KB):

```
dayjs('2021-04-24T05:48:50.650397026Z').format('DD.MM.YYYY, hh:mm:ss');
//24.04.2021, 05:48:50
```